# Fixing misclick in "Suggested edit" queue

Tags: support, suggested-edits, moderation

When reviewing the queue of suggested edits, I did the inevitable and thought to myself: "Improve!", but accidentally clicked "Approve" (perhaps related to not being a native English speaker).

As I clicked I immediately felt I clicked the wrong button, but I couldn't find any mechanism to revoke my action (or rather, change it and actually "Improve" the edit). If I try to edit the post in question which still has a pending user edit, instead of an edit box I get the message

> You have already reviewed this item.

and no opportunity to take any action.

Is there some reasoning behind not being able to revoke the action, or is it just unimplemented for the time being (or am I just bad at finding the function)? I feel that the review history list would be the obvious place.

[The edit in question](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/164237), if it is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to undo approvals. You can't undo *reject* votes either, and come to think about it, in Stack Exchange sites there's rarely an option to undo actions (apart from redacting a close vote, but this is a rather new feature).

If you misclicked and approved an edit that got applied due to your approval, you can always roll back the edit and make the necessary changes yourself.

Comment: All right, I would have kept an eye out for the edit in question, but I see that you rejected and edited it already, so all is well :-) . The strangest part I find about this is I was "blocked" from writing a new edit of the question until the case was settled, but since "Improve" was an action I (un)consciously chose not to take during review, an improved edit would imply a revocation of my review decision. I also see how revocation rights could be problematic, so I guess that is the way it is.

Comment: Most actions actually have some way to undo them. You can delete questions, answers, comments you posted; you can undelete questions, answers, and (moderators) comments; you can unupvote and undownvote recently voted for or since edited posts; you can unaccept accepted answers; you can rollback edits; ... While they're often more like 'corrective actions' instead of true 'undo', they're close enough. There are few really final actions, like offering bounties (and moderators can refund), flagging posts, or, well, reviews.